# Is Symmetric group on 5 symbols is the semi-direct product?

Tags: symmetric-groups, semidirect-product

Is the Symmetric group on 5 symbols is the semi-direct product of groups $A_5$ and $C_2$, i.e. $$S_5\cong A_5\rtimes C_2?$$ Here $A_5$ is considered as a normal subgroup. Please help.

Comment: What do you think? Does $S_5$ contain $A_5$ as a normal subgroup? Does it contain $C_2$ as a subgroup? Does it contain $C_2$ as a subgroup in such a way that every element of $S_5$ is uniquely expressible as $ab$ with $a\in A_5$ and $b\in C_2$? In other words, simply consult the textbook definition of "semidirect product" to have a readymade checklist for you to use in verifying $S_5$ is one.

Comment: Yes $A_5$ is normal in $S_5$. Also $C_2$ is a non normal subgroup of $S_5$. Further, every element of $S_5$ not in $A_5$ can be seen as an element of $ab$ for $a\in A_5$ and $b\in C_2$ with $b\neq e$, but how to find the uniqueness?

Comment: Suppose $a_1b_1=a_2b_2$. Then we can left-multiply by $a_2^{-1}$ and right-multiply by $b_1^{-1}$ to get $a=b$, where $a=a_2^{-1}a_1$ and $b=b_2b_1^{-1}$. But if you show $A_5$ and $C_2$ intersect trivially (if you picked the right $C_2$!) this means $a=b=e$, or in other words $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed,  we have a short exact sequence  $1\to A_5\to S_5\to C_2\to1$ that "splits".  The maps here are the natural ones.  You can check that  $\pi\circ i=\rm {id}_{C_2} $, where $i:C_2\hookrightarrow S_5$ is any of the $10$ inclusions.

Comment: Is it also true for $S_n$? I think it is.

Comment: Yes, $S_n\cong A_n\rtimes\mathbb Z_2$.